# Select into tables dynamically with variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some code to create tables based on a set of dates I define.

Example, I have 5 dates, and they are aren't consecutive. For any of these dates, I want to create a table and I am currently using a Select into.

I am having to do this 5 times, even though the only thing changing is the name of the new table created and the date. Is there a way to do this in an elegant way.

I started writing some code, but I am struggling to get it to loop through all the dates I want. The way I have written it currently, I only works if I edit the date at the start.

```
DECLARE @MyDate DATE;
SET @MyDate = '2019-01-01';
SET @TableName = 'Table1';

SELECT *
into @TableName
FROM Original_Table
WHERE  Query_Date = @MyDate;
```

Comment: You can't use a variables name to replace the name of an object. `INTO @TableName` would try to insert the values from your `SELECT` statement into the variable `@TableName`, not the object which has the value of `@TableName`; so your statement fail as `@TableName` is a `table` variable. This seems like an XY problem. Perhaps you could expand out and explain your full goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a one time thing or do you have to do this on a regular basis?
If it's the first, than I would just do it and get it over with.
If it's the latter, then I suspect something is very wrong with the way that system is designed - but assuming that can't be changed, you can create a stored procedure that will do this using dynamic SQL.

Something like this can get you started:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CreateTableBasedOnDate
(
    @MyDate DATE, 
    -- sysname is a system data type for identifiers: a non-nullable nvarchar(128).
    @TableName sysname
)
AS
-- 200 is long enough. Yes, I did the math. 
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(200) = 
    -- Note: I'm not convinced that quotename is enough to protect you from sql injection.
    -- you should be very careful with what user is allowed to execute this procedure.
    N'SELECT * into '+ QUOTENAME(@TableName) +N'
    FROM Original_Table 
    WHERE Query_Date = @MyDate;';

-- When dealing with dynamic SQL, Print is your best friend.
-- Remark this row and unremark the next only once you've verified you get the correct SQL
PRINT @SQL;

--EXEC sp_ExecuteSql @Sql, N'@MyDate Date', @MyDate

GO
```

Usage:

```
EXEC CreateTableBasedOnDate '2018-01-01', 'zohar';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @MyDate DATE, @TableName varchar(50);
SET @MyDate = '2019-01-01';
SET @TableName = 'Table1';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(4000);

SELECT @sql=N'
SELECT *
INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + '
FROM Original_Table
WHERE Query_Date = @MyDate;';
SELECT @params = N'@MyDate DATE';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, @params, @MyDate=@MyDate
```

Note that dynamic SQL can be dangerous as it opens up a path for SQL injection. Its fine if you are just using it in your own local scripts, but take care if you e.g. wrap this in a procedure that is more widely accessible.

Comment: I see your Schwartz is as big as mine... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would use dynamic SQL although I would add another variables for the schema:

```
DECLARE 
    @MyDate nVarchar(50) = '2019-01-01',
    @Schema nVarchar (50) = 'dbo',
    @TableName nVarchar(250) = 'Table1',
    @SQL nVarchar(500);

Set @SQL = '
SELECT *
     into '+ QUOTENAME(@Schema)+'.'+ QUOTENAME(@TableName) +'
  FROM Original_Table
  WHERE  Query_Date = '+ @MyDate +';
  '
  --print @SQL
  Exec(@SQL)
```

You can use the print statement to see how the SQL will look before executing this properly. You may also want to look at adding this as a stored procedure.